# Overriden method does not throw

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having some errors here. I cant quite figure out.
Hmmm.

```
class myException extends Exception {

    interface MyInterface {
        void myMethod () throws myException;
    }

    class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {

        @Override
        public void myMethod() throws MyException {
            System.out.println("in myMethod()");
            throw new MyException();
        }
    }

    class TheInterface { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyImplementation m;
        m = new MyImplementation();
        try {
            m.myMethod();
        } catch (MyException e) {
            System.out.println("MyException caught");
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Is it a compiler error, a runtime error, or a logic error? If it's a compiler error, what is the message? If it's a runtime error, what is the stack trace? If it's a logic error, what did you expect to happen, what actually happened? Above all else, what have you already tried to fix the problem you are having?

Comment: Add the errors you have to the question. It will help in solving your problem!

Answer (score 1):

You are using user defined exception and have not created that. Try this or use generic Exception

```
public class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public void myMethod() throws MyException {
        System.out.println("in myMethod()");
        throw new MyException();
    }

}

interface MyInterface {
    void myMethod () throws MyException;
}

public class MyException extends Exception {

}

public class TestThrowsException {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyImplementation m = new MyImplementation();
         try {
            m.myMethod();
         } 
         catch (MyException e) {
            System.out.println("MyException caught");
         }
    }
}
```

By test way:-

```
public class TestThrowsException {
    @Test(expected = MyException.class)
    public void shoudldThrowException() throws MyException {
         MyImplementation m = new MyImplementation();
         m.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have typo .

```
interface MyInterface {
    void myMethod () throws myException; // Change it to MyException
}
```

Also make sure you close braces properly

```
class myException extends Exception {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it as:

```
class myException extends Exception {}

interface MyInterface {
void myMethod () throws myException;
}

class MyImplementation
implements MyInterface {

@Override
public void myMethod() throws myException {
    System.out.println("in myMethod()");
    throw new myException();
}
}

public class TheInterface { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
MyImplementation m;
m = new MyImplementation();
try {
m.myMethod();
} catch (myException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("MyException caught");
}
}
}
```